# Trouble using Yii::app()->user

Tags: php, linux, yii

I have a strange problem when using `Yii::app()->user`, If I call it from one method I can't run almost anything until the running of the script has ended. For example let's say I have the following method:

```
public function actionFoo(){  
    Yii::app()->user; //just for the example, I know it doesn't mean anything
    sleep(30); //just so it won't finish right away
    echo "end of function Foo";  
}
```

Now if I call the `URL` related to `actionFoo` and after I'll try to call a different `URL` from another tab before the first one has finished the following happened:

1. If I enter an invalid `URL` that belongs to the same project I won't get a response until the end of `actionFoo`, meaning I won't get `404 Bad Request`.
2. If I enter a valid `URL` that's related to a method that also use `Yii::app()->user` - The same as in #1.
3. If I enter a valid `URL` that's related to a method that doesn't use `Yii::app()->user` - everything seems to work.

Hope everything is clear and if not feel free to ask.

Comment: Accessing `Yii::app()->user` opens the session. If your sessions are stored in files, [the second script will get stuck on that line and wait until the first one ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982654/using-same-session-id-within-two-php-scripts-at-same-time).

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your action function try calling `Yii::app()->end();`

So something like this:

```
function actionFoo(){
  Yii::app()->user;

  echo 'end of function foo';
  Yii::app()->end(); // add this as the last line in your function
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I wans't clear I want both methods to run at the same time if I call them from different tabs. I don't want one to wait for the other.